# How to pass shared props in several child components in Vue?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In react I can declare some object...

```
const shared_props = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: 'value3',
};
```

...and then pass it to several child components like this:

```
<ChildComponent1 {...shared_props} />
<ChildComponent2 {...shared_props} />
<ChildComponent3 {...shared_props} />
```

How can I do this in Vue?

Note that I'm not interesting in `v-bind:shared_props="shared_props"` because it's not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way :

```
<ChildComponent1 v-bind="shared_props" />
```

see more answers: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4962